# Authenticate to GCP via docker container - stackdriver: no project found with application default credentials error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, docker-compose

i'm using OpenTelemetry collector, running via docker-compose, to send telemetry data from an application to GCP among other exporters. Very new to GCP and OpenTelemetry!

I added GCP as exporter to my OpenTelemetry configuration, and in the services/telemetry/pipeline i have set it up to export Logs, Tracing and Metrics.

To authenticate to GCP, i have downloaded and installed google cloud sdk and ran the command  `gcloud auth application-default login` to generate credentials. I have made them accessible to the container by mounting them as a volume, grabbing the generated 'application_default_credentials.json' file, and setting it as the value to an environment variable 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'.

```
otel-collector:
  image: otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:0.61.0
  container_name: monitoring-collector
  restart: unless-stopped
  command: ["--config=/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml"]
  volumes:
    - ./collector/otel-collector-config.yaml:/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml
    - ~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json:/etc/otel/key.json
    - /<MyFilePath>:/etc/otel/config.yaml
  environment:
    - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/etc/otel/key.json
```

When i inspect the container, I can see the credentials are present. However, i'm getting an error which reads as follows from my container:

stackdriver: no project found with application default credentials

Does anyone know why this might be happening? to me, it implies the credentials have been picked up, but that it can't bind them to my existing project on GCP? i tried to read further into the documentation but went down a rabbit hole... At this point, i'm wondering are further permissions required to complete the authentication on GCP's end, or perhaps using ADC (Application Default Credentials) is not supported with our current project.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: I encourage you to create a Service Account specifically for this and to grant it appropriate roles rather than use `gcloud auth application-default` credentials. The documentation is sparse but these aren't equivalent. Using `gcloud auth application-default` uses your User (e.g.Google|Gmail) credentials as if they were a Service Account but there are differences. I suspect (!) that the `application_default_credentials.json`, because they don't reference a specific backing Project, are causing this issue. The OpenTelemetry client is trying to determine the Project from them and is unable.

Comment: As a best practice, I'd discourage **ever** using `gcloud auth application-default`. It was created as a convenience but it often causes more issues than benefits. Another consequence of it is that you're dependent on the Google services enabled in the Google-managed Project that backs `gcloud`. These can't be changed and are limited.

Comment: You cannot use `application_default_credentials.json` in the manner you are trying to. That file is an OAuth Client Secrets file and not a service account JSON key file.